# Split Character String Using Only Last Delimiter in r

Tags: r

I have a character variable that I would like to split into 2 variables based on a "-" delimiter, however, I would only like to split based on the last delimiter as there might be multiple "-" in the string.  Example:

```
Input          Output1  Output2
foo - bar      foo      bar
hey-now-man    hey-now  man
say-now-girl   say-now  girl
fine-now       fine     now
```

I've tried using strsplit to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on `stringi`  and `data.table`: reverse the string and split it into fixed items and then reverse back:

```
library(stringi)
x <- c('foo - bar', 'hey-now-man', 'say-now-girl', 'fine-now')

lapply(stri_split_regex(stri_reverse(x), pattern = '[-\\s]+', n = 2), stri_reverse)
```

If we want to make a `data.frame` with this:

```
y <- lapply(stri_split_regex(stri_reverse(x), pattern = '[-\\s]+', n = 2), stri_reverse)

y <- setNames(data.table::transpose(y)[2:1], c('output1', 'output2'))

df <- as.data.frame(c(list(input = x), y))

# > df
# input output1 output2
# 1    foo - bar     foo     bar
# 2  hey-now-man hey-now     man
# 3 say-now-girl say-now    girl
# 4     fine-now    fine     now
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a negative lookahead:

```
df <- tibble(input = c("foo - bar", "hey-now-man", "say-now-girl", "fine-now"))

df %>% 
    separate(input, into = c("output1", "output2"), sep = "\\-(?!.*-)", remove = FALSE)
```

Refs:

[1] https://frightanic.com/software-development/regex-match-last-occurrence/

[2] https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `gregexpr` :

```
a=c("foo - bar","hey-now-man","say-now-girl","fine-now")
lastdelim = tail(gregexpr("-",a)[[1]],n=1)
output1 = sapply(a,function(x) {substr(x,1,lastdelim-1)})
output2 = sapply(a,function(x) {substr(x,lastdelim+1,nchar(x))})
```

Comment: Received a few errors when trying to run:

    lastdelim = tail(gregexpr("-",x)[[1]],n=1)
    Error in gregexpr("-", x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: my bad, `x` should have been `a` (I changed the name on the way, and didn't updated it everywhere)

Answer (score 2):

Using *unglue* you would do :

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
df <- data.frame(input = c("foo - bar","hey-now-man","say-now-girl","fine-now"))
unglue_unnest(df, input, "{output1}{=\\s*-\\s*}{output2=[^-]+}", remove = FALSE)
#>          input output1 output2
#> 1    foo - bar     foo     bar
#> 2  hey-now-man hey-now     man
#> 3 say-now-girl say-now    girl
#> 4     fine-now    fine     now
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Came across this really awesome package [`strex`](https://rorynolan.github.io/strex/reference/before-and-after.html)

```r
library(strex)

input <- c('foo - bar', 'hey-now-man', 'say-now-girl', 'fine-now')

output1 <- str_after_last(input, "-")
# [1] " bar" "man"  "girl" "now" 
output2 <- str_before_last(input, "-")
# [1] "foo "    "hey-now" "say-now" "fine"
```

Note that there is a whitespace after "foo" and before "bar" because there is whitespace in the original string.

You can use `str_trim` or `str_squish` from the `stringr` package to remove the whitespace if that is needed. [link](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_trim.html)