# Separating data by delimiter in R: How can I specify at which delimiter (for example the 4th in a series of 5) that characters are separated?

Tags: r, tidyr, delimiter, data-wrangling

I have a column of unique photo IDs in a data frame. Each photo ID is comprised of a long string of characters and separated by a "_".

I want to split these IDs into columns using the delimiter "_".

This sounds easy enough, but I would like to split the characters into two specific columns at the last delimiter. For example if one of my photo IDs were:

"TV_Banana_122_Afternoon_Pre"

And I am trying to get the resulting split to be:

"TV_Banana_122_Afternoon" and "Pre"

Is there any way to specify that I want to separate this phrase by the 4th delimiter only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Character String Using Only Last Delimiter in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073722/split-character-string-using-only-last-delimiter-in-r)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44073722/split-character-string-using-only-last-delimiter-in-r see this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `strsplit` and the following regular expression to separate the string and then `do.call` and `rbind` to create a new dataframe with each part in its own column.

**CODE TO MATCH SPECIFIC # OF UNDERSCORES**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("TV_Banana_122_Afternoon_Pre"))

df_new <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(sub('(^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_(.*)$', '\\1 \\2', df), ' ')))

df_new
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                       X1  X2
1 TV_Banana_122_Afternoon Pre
```

---

Per the comment by @AnilGoyal,  if you needed to match an additional underscore you would just need to add an additional `_[^_]+` to the first match in `sub`. See example below.

**CODE TO MATCH A STRING WITH AN ADDITIONAL UNDERSCORE**

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c("TV_Banana_122_Afternoon_Test_Pre"))

df2_new <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(sub('(^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_(.*)$', '\\1 \\2', df2), ' ')))

df2_new
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                            X1  X2
1 TV_Banana_122_Afternoon_Test Pre
```

---

Also, if you have strings with varying #s of underscores, but you always want to split at the last underscore, you could just match the whole string up to the last underscore per the regex below.

**CODE TO MATCH THE LAST UNDERSCORE**

```
df_new2 <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(sub('(.*)_(.*)$', '\\1 \\2', df), ' ')))
df_new2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                   X1  X2
1 TV_Banana_122_Afternoon Pre
```

Comment: What is there are more than 4 `_`s

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, I added two additional solutions to my answer above to hopefully address your question, one to match a string with an additional underscore and another always match based on the last underscore in the string.

Comment: Hi @ksweet, Great!  If you feel like this fully answered your question please consider marking this as the accepted answer (i.e. checking the "check mark") and upvote (i.e. check the triangle pointing up). You can refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Help Center - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section for more info on those topics if needed.